# (OpenLayers) Empty value while transpoting Linestring data to an array

Tags: arrays, openlayers

im newbie at OpenLayers and i have a very basic problem, i'd be grateful if u help me.

I want to draw a line in a different method. (not with OpenLayers.Control).

Here is a piece of my code: (im taking coordinates as a function parameter)

```
        var openlayersCoordinates = [];
        coordinates.forEach(function (c) {
            openlayersCoordinates.push(new OpenLayers.Lonlat(c.y, c.x));
        });

        var polyPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(openlayersCoordinates);
        var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(polyPoint, null, {
            strokeColor: color,
            fillColor: color,
            strokeWidth: 5
        });
```

in Chrome debugger, polyPoint array returns as "undefined" (empty). so where am i wrong? Thanks for consideration!

Answer (score 0):

`OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString`'s constructor expects array of `OpenLayers.Geometry.Point` objects, not array of `OpenLayers.LonLat`

So, try changing

```
openlayersCoordinates.push(new OpenLayers.Lonlat(c.y, c.x));
```

to

```
openlayersCoordinates.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(c.x, c.y));
```